# Making a menu with copy, create, remove and rename

Tags: perl

The rename part does not have any code yet, but the rest does have the code to go along with it.

I keep getting that the variable for copy and remove aren't declared, but I did. What am I doing wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

sub menu {
  my $args = shift;
  my $title = $args->{title};
  my $choices = $args->{choices};

  while (1) {
    print "--------------------\n";
    print "$title\n";
    print "--------------------\n";
    for (my $i = 1; $i <= scalar(@$choices); $i++) {
      my $itemHeading = $choices->[$i-1][0];
      print "$i.\t $itemHeading\n";
    }
    print "\n?: ";
    my $i = <STDIN>; chomp $i;
    if ($i && $i =~ m/[0-9]+/ && $i <= scalar(@$choices)) {
      &{$choices->[$i-1][1]}();
    } else {
      print "\nInvalid input.\n\n";
    }
  }
}

my $menus = {};
$menus = {
  "1" => {
    "title" => "Menu 1 header",
    "choices" => [
      [ "Create file " , sub {
        print "Name of file you want to create:  ";
        my $createFile = <STDIN>;
        open my $fh, ">>", "$createFile" or die "can't open\n";
        print $fh "Here's that file you ordered\n";
        close $fh;

        print "done\n";
      }],

      [ "Rename a file" , sub {
        print "What file do you want to rename (add       ext): ";
        my $oldName = <STDIN>;
        print "What do you want to rename it: ";
        my $newName = <STDIN>;
      }],

      [ "Copy file" , sub {
        print "What file do you want to copy: "
        my $copyFile = <STDIN>;
        print "What do you want to call this file: :";
        my $newFile = <STDIN>;
        copy "$copyFile" , "$newFile" || die "can't copy";
      }],
      [ "Remove file" , sub {
        print "Which file do you want to remove";
        my removeF = <STDIN>;
        open my $fh;
        unlink "$removeF";
      }],
    },
  };

  menu($menus->{1});
```

Comment: What's the deal with the strange/inconsistent/lack of indentation? It's kind of rude to expect others to read your code when you can't be bothered to present a nicely formatted version of it!

Comment: I've cleaned up your code for you. Please do it yourself in the future. Consistent and meaningful indentation is an important self-documentation tool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cleaned up missing semicolons, dollar signs, braces, duplicated lines ... and formatting. I also added the missing `use File::Copy`.  Your code wasn't so far off at all but I can see that you got lost in so many little errors. So here is the most important note:

**Enter code a little  at a time and make sure that it runs cleanly and works as envisioned.** 
Add small sections of code and test, test, test. Build small, rounded, and crude (basic) components of functionality first, so that you can sensibly test them and your design. Then develop further.

Then each error is either easy to spot or educational.

Here is your code (just two functions), cleaned up so that it works and a little more

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use File::Copy qw(copy move);

sub menu {
    my $args = shift;
    my $title = $args->{title};
    my $choices = $args->{choices};

    while (1) {
        say $title, "\n", '-' x length $title;
        for my $i (1..@$choices) {
            my $itemHeading = $choices->[$i-1][0];
            say "$i.\t$itemHeading";
        }
        print "\n?: ";
        my $i = <STDIN>;
        chomp $i;
        if ($i && $i =~ m/[0-9]+/ && $i <= @$choices) {
            $choices->[$i-1][1]();
        } else {
            say "\nInvalid input.\n";
        }
    }
}

my $menus = {
    1 => {
        "title" => "Menu 1 header",
        "choices" => [
            [ "Create file " ,
                sub {
                    print "Name of file you want to create:  ";
                    my $createFile = <STDIN>;
                    chomp $createFile;
                    open my $fh, ">>", $createFile 
                        or die "Can't open $createFile: $!\n";
                    say $fh "Here's that file you ordered";
                    close $fh;

                    say "done";
                }
            ],
            [ "Rename a file" ,
                sub {
                    print "What file do you want to rename (add ext): ";
                    my $oldName = <STDIN>;
                    chomp $oldName;
                    if (not -e $oldName) {
                        say "\n\tNo file \"$oldName\"\n";
                        return;
                    }
                    print "What do you want to rename it: ";
                    my $newName = <STDIN>;
                    chomp $newName;          # what if it exists already?
                    move $oldName, $newName
                        or die "Can't move $oldName to $newName: $!";
                }
            ],
            [ "Quit", sub { exit } ]
        ]
    }
};

menu($menus->{1});
```

I also added the option to quit and some error checking.

A few notes

- There is rarely ever a need for a C-style `for` loop
- The `&` in front of a sub name has a very specific purpose. Normally it is not needed
- Add `$!` when you print error to actually see what it is, and/or use other [error variables](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Error-Variables)
- When an array is in scalar context its length is used, the number of elements; so there is no need for `scalar` in your conditions, just `1..@$choices` and `$i <= @$choices`
- Don't quote needlessly, it can lead to an *error*. Quoting is needed mostly when variables are interpolated in a string. No need for quotes in `say $var;` or `copy $file, $new ...`
- The one direct error was missing `chomp`s. With a resource that uses newlines (file, `STDIN`) that should be a basic *habit*. Omitting it in some situations may give cleaner flow but openness to that may invite debugging sessions, of "strange" errors possibly far down in code.

Please do your best to present a readable question with properly formatted code.

Answer (score 1):

You have an extremely detailed answer from [zdim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4653379/zdim). That's the one you should accept. But here's a list of what I had to fix in order to get your code running:

- Removed the duplicate `print "done\n"` and the following close brackets at the end of the first menu option subroutine (I removed them from your question while reformatting your code).
- Added the missing `use File::Copy`.
- Added a missing semicolon at the end of the first `print` statement in the copy option.
- Added a missing `$` to the `my removeF` statement in the remove option.

All of these were found by running your code through `perl -c` (which is Perl's built-in syntax checker).

In addition, you should take notice of all of zdim's suggested improvements.

And **please** format your code more carefully.